# How we can pass the DatePicker values into UITableView in UITextField?

Tags: iphone, ios5, uitextfield, uidatepicker

I have three text fields. The three fields are taken in UITableViewCell, this cell is passed into UITableViewController. In this tableviewcontroller I have taken date-picker for each custom cell textfield. It's showing date pickers.

My problem is, while changing the picker value is does not place on text..the value is showing in consoles but it's not showing in table view text field...

Answer (score 1):

Just check you have the right things in place

```
    - (void)datePickerValueChanged:(UIDatePicker*)datePicker
    {
       NSIndexPath *indexPath = selectedIndexPath;

           [tableData replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:datePicker.date];

           [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
```

let me know more in detail your issue

Comment: may i know here what is the "selectdIndexPath" property..?

Comment: it is the indexPath saved when the user selects the cell in tabledidselect call. you can use any form, just point to the cell data which needs to be changed

Comment: k,but i am selecting only Particular textfield,this textfields i was taken in customeCell.the customeCell passed into UITablviewController..so while i selected textfiedl its shows pickerview..when i changeed the value it does not placed into textfieds..

Comment: you need to change the value of textfield.text with the value of the picker view text selected manually, it is not done automatically. get the table->cell->textfield->text and set the value

Comment: yes,But i am using UIActionSheet for done action while change the values i clicked done

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried reloading your table view after chaging some value?

```
[myTableview reloadData];
```

Answer (score 0):

try working out this

```
 NSString *datePicValue;
- (void)viewpic:(DatePicker *)viewpic didSelectValue:(NSString *)value
{

      datePicValue=[[NSString alloc] initWithString:value];


}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     WorkOrderObj *obj=[app.bookdJobData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
     NSLog(@"workObj Count:%d",[app.bookdJobData count]);
     static NSString *CustomCellIdentifier = @"ContactLogCC";
     ContactLogCC *cell = (ContactLogCC *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: CustomCellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) 
   { 
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ContactLogCC" owner:self options:nil];
       {
           for (id oneObject in nib) if ([oneObject isKindOfClass:[ContactLogCC class]])
               cell = (ContactLogCC *)oneObject;
       }

      cell.lblDate.text=datePicValue;

  }
 return cell;
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
  {

      self.ViewDate = [[[DatePicker alloc] 
                  initWithNibName:@"DatePicker" 
                  bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] autorelease];
      ViewDate.contentSizeForViewInPopover=CGSizeMake(ViewDate.view.frame.size.width,      ViewDate.view.frame.size.height);

      ViewDate.delegate = self;
      self.popoverController = [[[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:ViewDate] autorelease];
      [self.popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(400,140,          ViewDate.view.frame.size.width, ViewDate.view.frame.size.height)
                                        inView:tblVw
                      permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionLeft
                                      animated:YES];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

table reload is procedure and another is like below

in .h file take one textField object like

```
    UITextField *txt_current;
```

in .m

```
    - (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField;
    {
       txt_current  = textField;
    }
    -(void) pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component{
    txt_current.text = @"selected value"
    }
```